# Adding data to a one to many core data model

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

Having some trouble getting my head around adding data into a core data model that has a one to many relationship.

Below is my model:

```
RecordDate - Relationship: records - One to Many with RecordWorkout.
RecordWorkout - Relationship: recExercises - One to Many With RecordExercise.
RecordExercise - Relationship: sets - One to Many With RecordSet.
RecordSet
```

RecordDate holds a single string variable date. (No duplicate variable of date is to be stored)

RecordWorkout holds a single string variable recWorkoutName. (No Duplicate variable of recWorkoutName can be stored.)

RecordExercise holds a single string variable recExerciseName. (Also No duplicate variable of recExerciseName can stored.

RecordSet holds three string variables (setLog, weight, reps). (Again no duplicate variable can be stored for the setLog variable.

Objective of Code:

Objective is that at the click of a button (Log Button), When button is clicked, code needs to compare the values on screen to the values already in the data store so no duplicate values are stored.

example:

date > workoutName > exercise > (Many sets e.g.: set1, set2, set3, set4)

At the first click of the button date, workoutName exerciseName and the first set details are stored. at the second click only new set data is stored.

Below is the code i am using, but it does not seem to store all the set values, some sets get missed from the data store or just the first set is stored.

```
setCount = setCount + 1;
NSString *weight = weightTextField.text;
NSString *reps = repsTextField.text;


NSString *setStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)setCount];

NSMutableString *log = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@%@ %@ %@ %@ %@", @"Set", setStr, @":", weight, @"kg X", reps, @"reps"];
[self.tempLog addObject:log];
[self.myTableView reloadData];
[weightTextField resignFirstResponder];
[repsTextField resignFirstResponder];
//the set is stored in a temporary mutable array (tempLog) just to show in tableview
//i would rather just store it in the actual entity and fetch from there

//Entities are initialised below
NSEntityDescription *recordDateEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordDate"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *recordWorkoutEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordWorkout"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *recordExerciseEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordExercise"
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *recordSetEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RecordSet"  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

//Data is fetched from the existing store to be compared with the data on screen
//This data is stored in mutable arrays (record date, recordworkouts, recordexercises, recordsets)
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RecordDate"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", dateLabel.text];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
self.recorddates = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRWRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RecordWorkout"];
NSPredicate *predicateRW = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recWorkoutName == %@", testLabel2.text];
[fetchRWRequest setPredicate:predicateRW];
self.recordworkouts = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRWRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRERequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RecordExercise"];
NSPredicate *predicateRE = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recExerciseName == %@", exNameLabel.text];
[fetchRERequest setPredicate:predicateRE];
self.recordexercises = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRERequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRSetRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"RecordSet"];
NSPredicate *predicateRSet = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"setLog == %@", setStr];
[fetchRSetRequest setPredicate:predicateRSet];
self.recordsets = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRSetRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

if ([self.recorddates count] == 0) {

    NSLog(@"No Dates Imported");

    RecordDate *newRecordDate = (RecordDate *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                               initWithEntity:recordDateEntity
                                               insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newRecordDate.date = dateLabel.text;

    RecordWorkout *newRecordWorkout = (RecordWorkout *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                                        initWithEntity:recordWorkoutEntity
                                                        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    newRecordWorkout.recWorkoutName = testLabel2.text;
    [newRecordDate addRecordsObject:newRecordWorkout];

    RecordExercise *newRecordExercise = (RecordExercise *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:recordExerciseEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    newRecordExercise.recExerciseName = exNameLabel.text;
    [newRecordWorkout addRecExercisesObject:newRecordExercise];



    RecordSet *newRecordSet = (RecordSet *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                            initWithEntity:recordSetEntity
                                            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    newRecordSet.setLog = setStr;
    newRecordSet.weight = weight;
    newRecordSet.reps = reps;
    [newRecordExercise addSetsObject:newRecordSet];

    NSLog(@"Set number one should be added to model: %@", setStr);

} else {

    NSLog(@"Dates Are Imported");

    RecordDate *prevRecordDate = (RecordDate *)[self.recorddates objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([self.recordworkouts count] == 0) {

        RecordWorkout *newRecordWorkout = (RecordWorkout *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                                            initWithEntity:recordWorkoutEntity
                                                            insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        newRecordWorkout.recWorkoutName = testLabel2.text;
        [prevRecordDate addRecordsObject:newRecordWorkout];

        RecordExercise *newRecordExercise = (RecordExercise *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:recordExerciseEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        newRecordExercise.recExerciseName = exNameLabel.text;
        [newRecordWorkout addRecExercisesObject:newRecordExercise];

        RecordSet *newRecordSet = (RecordSet *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                                initWithEntity:recordSetEntity
                                                insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        newRecordSet.setLog = setStr;
        newRecordSet.weight = weight;
        newRecordSet.reps = reps;
        [newRecordExercise addSetsObject:newRecordSet];

    } else {

        RecordWorkout *prevRecordWorkout = [self.recordworkouts objectAtIndex:0];


        if ([self.recordexercises count] == 0) {

            RecordExercise *newRecordExercise = (RecordExercise *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:recordExerciseEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


            newRecordExercise.recExerciseName = exNameLabel.text;
            [prevRecordWorkout addRecExercisesObject:newRecordExercise];

            RecordSet *newRecordSet = (RecordSet *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                                    initWithEntity:recordSetEntity
                                                    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            newRecordSet.setLog = setStr;
            newRecordSet.weight = weight;
            newRecordSet.reps = reps;
            [newRecordExercise addSetsObject:newRecordSet];

        } else {

            RecordExercise *prevRecordExercise = [self.recordexercises objectAtIndex:0];

            if ([self.recordsets count] == 0) {

                RecordSet *newRecordSet = (RecordSet *)[[NSManagedObject alloc]
                                                        initWithEntity:recordSetEntity
                                                        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

                newRecordSet.setLog = setStr;
                newRecordSet.weight = weight;
                newRecordSet.reps = reps;
                [prevRecordExercise addSetsObject:newRecordSet];

            } else {

                NSLog(@"Sets Already Imported");
            }
        }
    }

    NSError *errr;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&errr])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", errr);
    }
}
```

I got a feeling i can achieve what I am after using a much better organised code.

Thanks for any help offered.

ps. the code above is in the logButtonPressed method

Comment: Not storing all set values.. for example if i save 10 sets from 1 - 10. some set values are not stored.

Answer (score 1):

It can be so much simpler.

1) For fetching, it is sufficient to fetch just the dates and let Core Data take care of fetching the other stuff. Much more efficient und much less code. To "fetch" the related entities:

```
NSSet *workouts = date.workouts; 
NSSet *exercises = aWorkout.exercises;
NSSet *sets = anExercise.sets;
```

2) For checking if an item exists, e.g. dates just follow this pattern:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Date"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"%K = %@", attributeName, theDateStringToBeChecked];
request.fetchLimit = 1;
NSArray *dates = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request];
NSManagedObject *objectToUse = dates.count ? dates[0] : [NSEntityDescription 
   insertNewObjectForEntityName:"Date" 
   inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

You could greatly reduce your code by constructing a method that takes the entity string, the attribute string and the value to check. It would have a prototype like this:

```
-(NSManagedObject*)existingOrNewObjectWithEntityName:(NSString*)name
      attribute:(NSString*)attribute value:(NSString*)value;
```

Because your objects are subclasses of `NSManagedObject` you could then simply cast them to the right type.

Finally, don't forget to call `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];` to persist your changes.

Comment: Im not sure this could work. As initially there will be no dates stored. So there wont be no relationships to be set within the NSSets.

Comment: Not logical. How do have a workout without a date? Still, you could start by fetching the workouts and go down the chain in the same way.

Comment: The core data model has two sets of data. the Workouts data and the the Record Data. The workouts data is separate from the Record Data. Record data consists of the four entities i have described above. RecordDate holds just the Date. RecordWorkout holds just the workout name which is taken from the Workouts data. RecordExercise holds just the exercise name. RecordSet holds the set data.  Set: 1 Reps: 3 etc.

Comment: When the user first runs application Record Data will be empty because the user has not made any records.

Comment: The new question I have asked makes slightly more sense than this one. It states at the end what is going wrong with the code. Also what you mentioned in Number 1 for fetching is causing me problems. The fetch is retrieving NSArray...which when transferring to NSSet causes longlong value error